# python multiprocessping and pickle error using starmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, multiprocessing, pickle

I am using python's multiprocessing library but get the following error. The part of code related to multiprocessing is:

```
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())  # calculate stats for date in parallel
    print('Parallelize on {} CPUs'.format(mp.cpu_count()))
    date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]
    stats = pool.starmap(get_stats_for_date, [(path, dct, tfidf_model, curr_date, threshold)
                                              for curr_date in date_range])
    pool.close()
```

"""

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 304, in get_stats_for_date
    unclustered_articles_indices = get_articles_not_in_cluster(articles_day1, dct, tfidf_model, threshold=threshold)
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 154, in get_articles_not_in_cluster
    for idx, similarities in enumerate(index):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/similarities/docsim.py", line 643, in __iter__
    for chunk in self.iter_chunks():
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/similarities/docsim.py", line 667, in iter_chunks
    self.close_shard()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/similarities/docsim.py", line 436, in close_shard
    shard = Shard(self.shardid2filename(shardid), index)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/similarities/docsim.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.index = self.get_index()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/similarities/docsim.py", line 164, in get_index
    self.index = self.cls.load(self.fullname(), mmap='r')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 426, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1384, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xc3'.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 358, in <module>
    main()
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 348, in main
    df1, df2 = aggregate_by_year(db_path, dct, tfidf_model, year, threshold=threshold)
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 180, in aggregate_by_year
    stats += [aggregate_by_month(path, dct, tfidf_model, year, month, avg=True, threshold=threshold)]
  File "analysis_gensim.py", line 228, in aggregate_by_month
    for curr_date in date_range])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 276, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/econ/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xc3'.
```

I don't understand the issue. Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks

Comment: From your stacktrace I can see that exception is happening within analysis_gensim.py file. Check contents of your `index` variable. This will help you to understand issue more.

Answer (score 1):

I run into similar issue when running out of memory in container. Was running 16 threads against 26GB RAM hard limit and unpickling error started. Code was running ok on 64GB RAM and 16 threads -> so with hard limit of 56GB RAM for container, it is  now able to run through with 1,5GB Ram to spare. Changed my code to adjust amount of worker threads against available memory.

My error was:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-7:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap                                                                                                                                                                                  
    self.run()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xf5'.
```

Comment: Not sure about this. I have the same error and I do not hit max memory. Rebooting the machine works for a while then error starts happening again.

Comment: Also my problem was that I hit the pickle limit: "The maximum length of strings and byte arrays of both platforms is limited to 2 gigabytes (2^31 - 1)."

Comment: Little update on this: I found out that my RAM was corrupted and I had to exchange 2 modules. Since then all errors vanished.